# jQuery unwanted sorting of array output in Chrome and IE (FF working fine)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I have a jquery script which converts the options of a dropdown select box to ul list items using an array. Each option in the dropdown has a numerical option value, e.g.

```
<option value="12">Size S</option>
<option value="34">Size M</option>
<option value="7">Size L</option>
```

which get converted to a list like

```
<ul>
<li class="opt_12">Size S</li>
<li class="opt_34">Size M</li>
<li class="opt_7">Size L</li>
</ul>
```

In Firefox everything works as expected and the list items appear in the same order as the dropdown options. However IE and Chrome seem to sort the option values of the array automatically by option value in descending order. 
So instead of size order S,M,L,XL like in the dropdown, in Chrome & IE I get a list with something like XL,M,S,L.

I noticed one thing: When I use `var options = Array;` to construct the array, Firefox displays the list elements in the right order and Chrome and IE the wrong one. When I use `var options = [];`, all three tested browsers display the list in the wrong order.

Below is the relevant code of the script which I use to transform the dropdown into list items:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.visualAttribute = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            useTitle: false,
            attrClicked : function(data) {
                return true;
            },
            attrUpdated : function(data) {
            }
        };
        var settings = $.extend(defaults, options);

        //loop all attributes
        var selectbox_counter = 0;
        return this.each(function() {
            //use counter for a unique class for each wrapper
            selectbox_counter++;

            //store reference to attribute selectbox
            var selectbox = $(this);

            //hide the default dropdown (but keep it in dom for posting the required values)
            $(this).css('position', 'absolute').css('left', '-100000px').show();

            //insert wrapper for options
            var wrapper = $('<ul />')
                    .attr("class", "la_wrapper")
                    .attr("id", "la_wrapper_" + selectbox_counter)
                    .appendTo($(this).parent());

            $(this).parent().append('<div style="clear:both"></div>');

            if (selectbox.attr("id") != "") {
                wrapper.attr("rel", selectbox.attr("id"));
            }

            //store all values of the dropdown in an array
            var options = [];
            var option_counter = 0;
            var description = '';

            selectbox.children('option').each(function() {
                option_counter++;

                if (option_counter == 1) {
                    //first option contains the description, e.g. 'please select size'
                    description = $(this).text();
                }

                //only use option if has a value
                var value = $(this).val();
                if (value != '') {
                    options[value] = ({value : value, text : $(this).text()});
                }
            });

            //loop all stored options and create custom html
            if (options.length) {
                for (var index in options) {
                    if (!isNaN(index)) {
                        var value = index;
                        var text = options[index].text;
                        if (!settings.useTitle) {
                            description = '';
                        }
                        wrapper.append('<li title="' + description + '" class="opt_' + value + '"><a href="#' + value + '">' + text + '</a></li>');
                    }
                }
            }

            //set custom options to same value as current selectbox value (only needed in rare cases)
            var current_value = selectbox.val();
            if (current_value > 0) {
                $("#la_wrapper_" + selectbox_counter + ' li.opt_' + current_value + ' a').addClass('selected');
            }

            //event handler for catching a clicked attribute
            $("#la_wrapper_" + selectbox_counter + ' li a').click(function() {

                var value = $(this).attr("href").split('#')[1];

                //use callback
                if (!settings.attrClicked(options[value])) {
                    return false;
                }

                //set value and class
                selectbox.val(value);
                $("#la_wrapper_" + selectbox_counter + ' .selected').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');

                //use callback
                settings.attrUpdated(options[value]);

                return false;
            });
        });
    };
    })(jQuery);
```

How can I prevent IE and Chrome from "autosorting" the array and keep/transfer the original order of the dropdown options in the resulting list?

Comment: You want to use [`array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), like I point out in my answer... `;)`

Comment: OK thanks for the advice, I will try that and come back tomorrow with the result (2:40 am here) :)

Comment: I can confirm that your solution works perfectly, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order is important, don't use the `value` of the option as the array key, just do an `append` (P.S. use `[]`, not `Array`—that isn't doing what you think it's doing)

```
var options = [];
var option_counter = 0;
var description = '';

selectbox.children('option').each(function() {
    option_counter++;

    //only use option if has a value
    var value = $(this).val();
    if ( value ) {
        options.push({value : value, text : $(this).text()});
    }
});
```

Then, when looping, get rid of the `if (options.length)` altogether, and use a regular for loop:

```
for (var i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
    var value = options[i].value;
    var text = options[i].text;
    if (!settings.useTitle) {
        description = '';
    }
    wrapper.append('<li title="' + description +
                   '" class="opt_' + value +
                   '"><a href="#' + value + '">' + text +
                   '</a></li>');
}
```

Comment: I think they want to preserve the order - they said `How can I prevent IE and Chrome from "autosorting" the array and keep the original order of the dropdown options?`. To me, that means they need an array, not an object

Comment: @Ian You're right, I was focusing on the fact that OP was trying to use `value` as the key in the array, and thinking he was getting values sorted but not the text, causing the problem. But I think your interpretation is right.

Comment: Just wanted to point it out :) I know you included both suggestions. Either way, there's a lot of things wrong with the code, and I'm not 100% sure about several expectations

Comment: The code above is not my work (I am just starting out with JS :)) and I stripped out some parts which I did not consider important, I will edit the post to include the original code.

Comment: @Socrates I just made a small change, but it should work correctly now. You should use `push` to add elements to the array. Not sure what you stripped out, I only included the relevant portions from your post...

Comment: @nbrooks You sir, are a hero!! I can`t thank you enough, I have spent the last two days trying to fix this. I just tested your code and it works perfectly! Stackoverflow is simply the best community out there :)

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate an array with this:

```
for (var index in options)
```

you are not getting a guaranteed order as you are just iterating properties of an object (not array indexes) which by specification have no guaranteed order.  You should be using this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
```

to iterate an array in the array order.  The first form iterates properties of an object in no particular order.  The latter form iterates array elements in array index order (which gives you the actual array elements in their array order).

In addition, you declare an array with this:

```
var options = [];
```

or

```
var options = new Array();
```

You should not be using:

```
var options = Array;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're using `for...in` to enumerate the properties.

Enumeration order for properties of an object (including an array) is undefined in ECMAScript so far.  There is a proposal for ECMAScript 6 to define the order as follows, more or less: "first all properties whose names look like integers, in numeric order, then all other properties in the order they were added".  This is the behavior Chrome and IE implement.  The Firefox behavior is somewhat complicated and depends on whether your object is an array or not and if it's an array on which exact property names got used and in what order and what the length of the array is and a few other things.

In any case, if you want to enumerate the values in order, just store them in an array using `array.push()` and then enumerate the array's indices.  So replace `options[value] = ...` with `options.push(...)` and replace `for (var index in options)` with `for (var index = 0; index < options.length; ++index)` and get the value from `options[index].value` just like you get the text already.